# PHP 7.1 replace multiple values with dynamic variables

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I'm quite new with PHP and although I've found a way to solve my issue, I feel that surely there is a much easier way to achieve the same result:

Here what I need to do:

I have a String like this (in the real one there are some 25 values to be replace)

```
"We have received ##AMOUNT## ##CURRENCY## for your OrderID n. ##ORDER_ID##"
```

In this string I have to replace
`##AMOUNT##` with value of variable named `$AMOUNT`
`##CURRENCY##` with value of variable `$CURRENCY`
`##ORDER_ID##` with value of variable `$ORDER_ID`

currently I created an array:

```
$flds=['AMOUNT','CURRENCY','ORDER_ID'];
```

and I replace using a loop and dynamic variables:
but I've seen str_replace accepts also arrays and therefore could build a more elegant (and efficient) solution
but...I cannot find it

can give some hints?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you cant find it? http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Please provide a basic attempt...so you need to replace something in a string...do a small research for "string replace", you will be surprised (Lawrence Cherone made the spoiler)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393297/replace-same-character-several-times-with-different-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), if you got arbitrary variables you can use [compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) to put them in an array.

```
<?php
$str = "We have received ##AMOUNT## ##CURRENCY## for your OrderID n. ##ORDER_ID##";

$AMOUNT = 123;
$CURRENCY = 'GBP';
$ORDER_ID = 20123;

$find = ['##AMOUNT##','##CURRENCY##','##ORDER_ID##'];
$replace = compact('AMOUNT', 'CURRENCY', 'ORDER_ID');

echo str_replace($find, $replace, $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/1E2Mm

**Result:**

We have received 123 GBP for your OrderID n. 20123

If your looking for a way to just define your variables/placeholders once and then match and replace, you can do it like:

```
<?php
$str = "We have received ##AMOUNT## ##CURRENCY## for your OrderID n. ##ORDER_ID##";

$AMOUNT = 123;
$CURRENCY = 'GBP';
$ORDER_ID = 20123;

$find = ['AMOUNT', 'CURRENCY', 'ORDER_ID'];

echo str_replace(
    array_map(function($v){ return '##'.$v.'##'; }, $find), 
    compact(...$find), 
    $str
);
```

https://3v4l.org/ekHYB

Comment: yes, this was the target: define only once the tags to replace considering that name of variable would be the same as tag

Answer (score 2):

I would make a simple template class to parse it,

```
class SimpleTemplate
{      
    protected $src;        
    protected $vars;
    
    public function __construct($src)
    {
        $this->src = $src;
    }
    
    public function assign($key, $value)
    {
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }
    
    public function out()
    {
        return str_replace(array_keys($this->vars),$this->vars,$this->src);
    }        
}

$T = new SimpleTemplate("We have received ##AMOUNT## ##CURRENCY## for your OrderID n. ##ORDER_ID##");
$T->assign('##AMOUNT##', 'foo');
$T->assign('##CURRENCY##', 'bar');
$T->assign('##ORDER_ID##', 'hello');

echo $T->out();
```

Outputs:

```
"We have received foo bar for your OrderID n. hello"
```

You can see it [here live](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1d832ff0934a7472448695f1c09f08cb47e1261):

And you can always expand on it and add features, like removing the `##` from the assignment, and removing any un-used tags. etc...

Basically it's just an array management tool for your variables.  Because we are building an array like this:

```
[
  '##AMOUNT##' => 'foo',
  '##CURRENCY##' => 'bar',
  '##ORDER_ID##' => 'hello'
];
```

And then using `str_replace` we use the keys as the search, the value as the replacement value.

If you want to remove the `##` from the tag assignment just change this:

```
public function assign($key, $value)
{
    $this->vars['##'.$key.'##'] = $value;
}
```

And then call like this:

```
$T->assign('AMOUNT', 'foo');
```

The real benefit here, is having a class to implement your logic in.  It keeps it clean and re-usable.

### UPDATE

As @LawrenceCherone mentioned in the comments, you can get a cleaner interface by using a couple magic methods.

```
class SimpleTemplate
{      
    protected $src;
    protected $vars;
    
    public function __construct($src)
    {
        $this->src = $src;
    }
    
    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->vars['##'.strtoupper($key).'##'] = $value;
    }
    
    public function __toString()
    {
        return str_replace(array_keys($this->vars),$this->vars,$this->src);
    }     
}

$T = new SimpleTemplate("We have received ##AMOUNT## ##CURRENCY## for your OrderID n. ##ORDER_ID##");
$T->Amount = 'foo';  //any casing works because of the transforms, in __set
$T->CURRENCY = 'bar';
$T->order_id = 'hello';

echo $T; //using __toString() lets us just output the class as our result string.
```

Specifically `__set` and `__toString`. For this one I did a few transforms on the `key` so as to make it a bit less error prone, and a bit less ugly.  For example the use of Mixed Casing for the dynamic Properties.  By using `strtoupper` they can be input in any case, and removing the `#` prevents having to wrap them like this `$T->{'##AMOUNT##'} = 'foo';`

The last thing I will add, is if you can have "tags" that are not assigned but want them removed you can use this regx to remove them.

```
    public function __toString()
    {
        $str = str_replace(array_keys($this->vars),$this->vars,$this->src);
        return preg_replace(['/##\w+##/', '/\s{2,}/'], ['', ' '], $str); //remove any left over ##{word}## tags, and compress any run-on spaces.
    }
```

You can see an example of this [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd8d5d0821b72c64bcb6c4ef7832d4fb030b8a55)

The second one in the array `/\s{2,}/`,   just takes run on spaces and compresses them to a single space, so if you have like 4 spaces it becomes a single space.  It's not well documented but `preg_replace` can take an array just like `str_replace` does.

This is why I suggest building up a class, it gives you a nice place to implement all this "stuff" if you want, and not have to keep re-writing it all the time.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - that's a good sugestion, I was trying to keep it as simple as possible.  I can add that in.  I was trying to avoid `$T->{'##AMOUNT##'}`  So I will do it like `$T->AMOUNT = 'foo';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function with two arrays, one of the searched words and the second of the replacements:

```
 $words = ["##AMOUNT##", "##CURRENCY##", "##ORDER_ID##"];
 $replaces = [$AMOUNT,$CURRENCY,$ORDER_ID];
 $newString = str_replace($words, $replaces, $string);
 echo $newString;
```

Comment: This will replace `##AMOUNT##` with `AMOUNT`. I don't think OP needs this.

Comment: I bet you had in mind `["{$AMOUNT}", "{$CURRENCY}", "{$ORDER_ID}"]` for $replaces array

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant way is `printf` funtion.

```
vsprintf("We have received %s %s for your OrderID n. %s", array($AMOUNT, $CURRENCY, $ORDER_ID));
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php

Comment: This would be the most elegant solution so far.. but with this:
`<?php
 $AMOUNT='123';
 $CURRENCY='EUR';
 $ORDER_ID='Z1234';
 printf("We have received %s %s for your OrderID n. %s", [$AMOUNT, $CURRENCY, $ORDER_ID]);
 $a=sprintf("We have received %s %s for your OrderID n. %s", array($AMOUNT, $CURRENCY, $ORDER_ID));
 echo $a;
?>`
I got some errors both not only in `sprintf` but also in `printf`: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iper_eu\admin\test\t3.php on line 5`
and the same in line 6 where there is sprintf.

Comment: Updated the answer @Joe, the right function for your problem (array) is `vsprintf`. Tested and worked: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae54bf399092467dda33d9ddb99a61491c8ad7c5

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` will work with arrays. If `$find` is an array and `$replace` is a string it will replace everything in `$find` with the string in `$replace` if both are arrays it will replace each corresponding element `$find[index]` with their corresponding `$replace[index]` example:

```
$find = ["find1", "find2" ];
$replace = [ "replace1", "replace2" ];

$string = "Find find1 and find2"; 

echo str_replace($find, $replace, $string); // "Find replace1 and replace2"
```

However there is a small catch in that the replacements are done in sequence. It generally isn't a problem until you encounter something like:

```
$find = [ "find", "find2" ];
$replace = [ "replace", "replaceXX2" ];
$string = "Find find1 and find2"; 

echo str_replace($find, $replace, $string); // "Find replace1 and replace2"
```

Why? Because it will replace both the "find" word and the "find" that is part of find2 with replace before it even looks for "find2".

If you want to avoid that you can use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) as follows:

```
$find = [ "find" => "replace" , "find2" => "replaceXX" ];

$string = "Find find1 and find2"; 

echo strtr($string, $find); // "Find replace1 and replaceXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

An another way with @Lawrence Cherone's answer. Maybe you want to use `key => value` list.

```
<?php
$message = "We have received ##AMOUNT## ##CURRENCY## for your OrderID n. ##ORDER_ID##";

$messageParameters = [
    'AMOUNT' => 83,
    'CURRENCY' => 'USD',
    'ORDER_ID' => 3271096
    ];

$parsedMessage = str_replace(
    array_map(function($v){ return '##'.$v.'##'; }, array_keys($messageParameters)), 
    array_values($messageParameters), 
    $message
);

echo $parsedMessage;
```

**Result:**

```
We have received 83 USD for your OrderID n. 3271096
```

https://3v4l.org/9b7lO